# Let $ A\subset$ $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an open set, $a\in A $. Show that $A \setminus \{a \}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis

I think the following can be done:

Since $ a\in A $, just take $ 0 <r <\lVert a- x \rVert $. Thus $ B (a, r) ​​\subset A $

Therefore $ A \setminus \{a \} $ is open.

Any suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $A$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ , $a \in A$ and you want to prove $A \backslash \{a\}$ is an open set?

Comment: Hint: points are closed and finite intersection of open sets is open

Comment: I don't see how your proof works. Instead, consider the following. For any point in $b\in A\setminus\{a\}$, $d(a,b)=r_b>0$. What is $\bigcup\limits_{b\in A\setminus\{a\}}A\cap B(b,r_b)$?

Comment: If $x\in A\setminus\{a\}$, since $A$ is open there is a ball $B_r(x)$ with center $x$ and some positive radius, such that $B_r(x)\subset A$. If you take as new radius $s=\min(r,\|x-a\|)$ the ball $B_s(x)$ will be inside $A\setminus\{a\}$, since $B_s(x)\subset B_r(x)$ and it doesn't contain $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is wrong. An open set $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a set with the property that for any $x \in D$ there exists some $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq D$. In other words, if a point belongs to $D$, an entire ball centered in that point is included in $D$.
Note that the point $a$ in your problem does not belong to $A \backslash \{a \}$. So showing that there is a ball centered in $a$ that is contained in $A$ does not solve the exercise.
You have two options:

1. Try to use the definition for proving that $A \backslash{a}$ is open.
2. Just observe that $\{a \}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence $\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{a \}$ is open and therefore $A \backslash \{a\} = A \cap \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{a \}$ is open as well (being a intersection of two open sets).

Answer (score 1):

Your set is the intersection of two open sets and is therefore open. Note that singletons in euclidean space are closed and therefore have open complements.